# CMake link to dynamic library generated by call to ExternalProject_Add

Tags: c++, dll, cmake, eclipse-cdt, glfw

I have a small test program that I want to link to GLFW. I am currently able to download, configure and build the .dll using `ExternalProject_Add` command. When I build my test program I get an executable that doesn't run because it can't find the .dll. If I manually copy the .dll to the directory where the executable is, it runs just fine.

How do I get my executable to properly link to the library?

Is there a way to automatically copy the .dll to where it needs to be?

What is the best way to ensure that, when it comes time to package my program, the library is available to use and easily accessible?

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (GLFW-test)

set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/app )
set( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib )

# Include OpenGL
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
if (OPENGL_FOUND)
    include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
    link_libraries(${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
endif()

# Add directories for library linkage
set(GLFW_LIB_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/downloads/deps/Build/GLFW_EX/src)
link_directories(${GLFW_LIB_DIR})

# Download and unpack dependencies at configure time
configure_file(deps-CMakeLists.txt downloads/CMakeLists.txt)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" .
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/downloads)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/downloads)

add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/downloads/deps/Source/GLFW_EX
                 ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/downloads/deps/Build/GLFW_EX
                 EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL )

include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/downloads/deps/Source/GLFW_EX/include)

add_executable(GLFW-test src/GLFW-test.cpp)
target_link_libraries (GLFW-test glfw3 ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})

add_custom_command(TARGET GLFW-test POST_BUILD        # Adds a post-build event to MyTest
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different     # which executes "cmake - E copy_if_different..."
        "${GLFW_LIB_DIR}/glfw3.dll"                   # <--this is in-file
        $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:GLFW-test>)                 # <--this is out-file path
```

dep-CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (GLFW-dl)

include(ExternalProject)
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES EP_BASE "./deps/")

# Include GLFW
ExternalProject_Add (
       GLFW_EX
       GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/glfw/glfw.git"
       GIT_TAG "master"
       CMAKE_ARGS -DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF
                  -DGLFW_BUILD_TESTS=OFF
                  -DGLFW_BUILD_DOCS=OFF
                  -DGLFW_INSTALL=OFF
                  -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON
       UPDATE_COMMAND ""
       TEST_COMMAND      "" )
```

**UPDATE:**
The way I am using `ExternalProject_Add` is described on this site: https://crascit.com/2015/07/25/cmake-gtest/
It allows the external projects to be configured and built only once during the configure phase of my project. I have changed the directories around a bit from their test program to make things a little easier for when I eventually add more external projects. The test project on the site does not seem to account for dynamic libraries which is what I am trying to do.

**UPDATE 2:**
I've added 2 `set` commands to help clean up the build directory towards the top of the CMakeLists file. I also added a command at the bottom which copies .dll that is built from the `ExternalProject_Add` command to where I need it (next to the final executable). That seems to work for Windows, but it seems a bit hacky and doesn't resolve the errors in my IDE, which is currently Eclipse. Is there still a better way to do this?

*Helpful Related topics:*

- [Setting the RPATH for external projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32786461/setting-the-rpath-for-external-projects)
- [Cmake on Windows doesn't add shared library paths (works on linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433308/cmake-on-windows-doesnt-add-shared-library-paths-works-on-linux)
- [How to copy DLL files into the same folder as the executable using CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671916/how-to-copy-dll-files-into-the-same-folder-as-the-executable-using-cmake)

Comment: Your `execute_process()` calls build *another project* in the binary dir of the *current* one. I wonder how CMake processes that without errors. Actually, you can call `ExternalProject_Add()` in the same project which uses external library. No needs to create *separate* project for that call.

Comment: Yes, however the `execute_process()` allows me to build the other project only once and during the configure phase of my project instead of everytime I build my project. The technique is described here: http://crascit.com/2015/07/25/cmake-gtest/

Comment: Note, that in the article you refer external project is downloaded and built to `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/gtest-download`, not to `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}` as it is done in your project. Fix that issue and check whether your problem is still persisted.

Comment: I have already been there and done that. It does not make a difference, especially since the dll that is built gets put in another subdirectory anyway.

Comment: Please, update your question to reflect changes which you have made. Just for being sure that previous issue is completely gone off, and new issues are not appears.

Comment: I've updated my question with things I've tried.

Comment: You still build external project in the binary directory of main project: `configure_file` and `execute_process`  both works in `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}`. Two builds in the same directory may confuse CMake. Change build directory of external project to, e.g. `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/GLFW-download`.

Comment: I just updated my project and question to move the external project to another directory and it still doesnt work.

Comment: As for problems with Eclipse, try to rename your main project or executable: according to [this manual](http://sgpsproject.sourceforge.net/JavierVGomez/index.php/How_to_configure_a_C/C%2B%2B_project_with_Eclipse_and_CMake), Eclipse may have problems with executable and project named equally.

Comment: BTW, as your executable is linked with library from external project, you should make this executable dependent from external project: `add_dependencies(GLFW-test GLFW_EX)`.

Comment: `add_dependencies` "fails" from Policy CMP0046 due to GLFW_EX being in executed in a different process. I've tried using `glfw` instead of `GLFW_EX` since that is the target that gets output from the other project, but then I get `undefined references` for GLFW functions during the build of my project.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I forget again that you actually build external project at configuration step, so you don't need to `add_dependencies()` from it. What about renaming main project name or executable (both are `GLFW-test`)? Does it resolve Eclipse issues?

Comment: It looks as though the renaming of the project seems to have worked. I also installed the plugin that was linked to on the link you provided. This forced me to restart Eclipse which may have also had something to do with the errors.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get my executable to properly link to the library?

As your [second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433308/cmake-on-windows-doesnt-add-shared-library-paths-works-on-linux) states, there is no other way than to have .dll in the same directory as executable.

> Is there a way to automatically copy the .dll to where it needs to be?

In you main project you already use variable `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` for setup directory where executables and `.dll`s should be placed after build. You can pass this variable to `ExternalProject_add` for force it to use same conventions:

```
ExternalProject_Add (...
    CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}
    ...
)
```

> What is the best way to ensure that, when it comes time to package my program, the library is available to use and easily accessible?

Packaging just uses *install-tree* of your project. So it is sufficient to install executables and libraries into same location:

```
set(INSTALL_RUNTIME_DIR bin)
install(TARGETS GLFW-test
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${INSTALL_RUNTIME_DIR}
)
install(FILES ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/glfw3.dll
    DESTINATION ${INSTALL_RUNTIME_DIR}
)
```

Note, that target `GLFW_EX` obtained from external project has no special type(like executable or library), so you need to install its deliverables using plain filenames.